# Update Users Laravel Eloquent Active Directory JSON

Tags: php, json, laravel

I am trying to update a Laravel Users table with eloquent from an Active Directory JSON dump. I have gotten as far as parsing out the JSON and removing user records from MYSQL that are in MYSQL but not in the JSON. I'm struggling to figure out how to Insert new records from the JSON that are not in the MYSLQ / Update existing records in the MYSQL that have changed in the JSON.

Here is my code so far

```
    //Read AD Users JSON File
    $strJsonFileContents = file_get_contents(public_path('ADusers.json'));
    //Remove UTF8 Bom Characters and strip slashes
    $bom = pack('H*','EFBBBF');
    $strJsonFileContents = preg_replace("/^$bom/", '', $strJsonFileContents);
    //run twice for double slashes
    $strJsonFileContents = stripslashes($strJsonFileContents);
    $strJsonFileContents = stripslashes($strJsonFileContents);
    $strJsonFileContents = str_replace('/', '', $strJsonFileContents);

    //JSON to Object
    $decoded_json = json_decode($strJsonFileContents);
    
    //Get list of EMPIDs from JSON into array to remove from database
    $id_list = implode(",", array_map(function ($val) { return (int) $val->extensionAttribute2; },$decoded_json));
    $id_list_arr = explode (",", $id_list);
    //Delete records from database that are not in JSON Array
    $numDelete = DB::table('users')->select()->whereNotIn('extensionAttribute2', $id_list_arr)->delete();
```

I also realize that the DB::table('users') is probably not quite the right way, so if somebody can help me figure out how to use the User model and how to update/insert from the JSON to the MYSQL, I would so greatly appreciate it.